# Software for converting an HTML page to PSD with layers

Tags: screenshot, photoshop, psd

I am looking for a tool to convert an HTML page to its basic components (images, text) and put each of them to photoshop layer. It's something similar to a layer aware screen grabber for web pages only.

I discovered that it already exists for Mac: http://www.pagelayers.com/ but I need an online or Windows version.
You can easily understand what I need by having a look to grabbed PSD of the twitter page: http://www.pagelayers.com/example-psds/

From a development point of view it's not hard to implement.